# Microsoft Outlook automation: Capturing a Save event

Tags: c#, events, outlook, office-interop

I need to capture the save of a task in outlook (2010), but neither `taskItem` or the inspector seem to have such an event. So I set up for capturing the inspector close:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    inspectors = this.Application.Inspectors;
    inspectors.NewInspector += new Outlook.InspectorsEvents_NewInspectorEventHandler(Inspectors_NewInspector);
}

private void Inspectors_NewInspector(Outlook.Inspector inspector)
{
    Outlook.TaskItem taskItem = inspector.CurrentItem as Outlook.TaskItem;
    if (taskItem != null)
    {
        if (taskItem.EntryID == null)
        {
            ((Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event)taskItem).Close += new Outlook.ItemEvents_10_CloseEventHandler(Task_Close);
        }
    }
}
```

If I close the inspector the event handler is called, however if I click Save and Close it is not.
Bottom line is that I need to capture when the user saves the task (so that I can post process the subject.) Is there an event  I can use that will capture that Save and Close button?

Comment: Not sure if this article will help but have you taken a look at this Jessica? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/93288/Add-in-Programming also MSDN [Inspector.CurrentItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869722.aspx)

Comment: This link may help as well http://www.add-in-express.com/forum/read.php?FID=5&TID=10910

Comment: This one seems to be the closest to what you are doing / looking for http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/save-close-outlook-e-mail-draft-without-51701.aspx

Comment: Save() is actually Write() and its not on the inspector item but the inspector.CurrentItem (duh)  - thnx

Answer (score 1):

Instead of defining "Outlook.TaskItem taskItem;" locally, define it on top with global visibility.